# How do I get emacs on a newly installed Fedora 20 system?

Tags: fedora, emacs, yum

I have upgraded from Linux Fedora 12 to Fedora 20 by buying a new computer, and the shop has kindly installed Linux for me from the DVD I bought for the purpose. I assume he did the most basic installation he could. It is all strange coming from 12, and I am a bit lost. The first thing I tried to do was use emacs, but it is not recognised as a command.

I had already looked for emacs like this

```
[root@localhost ~]# cd /usr/share/emacs/
[root@localhost emacs]# ls
site-lisp
[root@localhost emacs]#
```

So it looked to me as if emacs was there and just not found.

```
[root@localhost emacs]# emacs
bash: emacs: command not found... 
[root@localhost emacs]# yum install emacs
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/linux/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14]   curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: linuxdownload.adobe.com"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: fedora/20/i386. Please verify its path and try again
[root@localhost emacs]#
```

So, please what is wrong, and how do I get out of it?

In answering this, please treat me as a complete novice, so I can fully understand the answer. I don't immediately recognise most of the cryptic names for things, nor is it easy to discover, out of context, what they mean.

==============================================================

That was my original question, so, in response to several answers I tried all this:

```
[root@localhost emacs]# yum search emacs
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/linux/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: linuxdownload.adobe.com"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: fedora/20/i386. Please verify its path and try again
[root@localhost emacs]# yum check-update
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
adobe-linux-i386                                         |  951 B     00:00     
fedora/20/i386/metalink                                  |  34 kB     00:00     
http://ftp.ps.pl/pub/Linux/fedora-linux/releases/20/Everything/i386/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: ftp.ps.pl"
Trying other mirror.
   .....
```

and so on, miles of it, until I stopped it, thus:

```
... http://sunsite.mff.cuni.cz/MIRRORS/fedora.redhat.com/linux/releases/20/Everything/i386/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: sunsite.mff.cuni.cz"
Trying other mirror.
^Z
[1]+  Stopped    yum check-update
```

... and then tried this as well:

```
[root@localhost emacs]# yum refresh
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
No such command: refresh. Please use /usr/bin/yum --help
[root@localhost emacs]# yum install emacs
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Existing lock /var/run/yum.pid: another copy is running as pid 4647.
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
The other application is: yum
Memory :  24 M RSS ( 51 MB VSZ)
Started: Wed Feb 26 15:31:47 2014 - 06:04 ago
State  : Traced/Stopped, pid: 4647
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiti .....
```

And there I gave up

I would be grateful for more suggestions on haw to get out of this impasse. Please, *please,* only answer if you do really recognise the problem and do know how to fix it. I have spent a lot of time trying other similar ideas from very kindly intended people who thought they *might* have a solution. Perhaps the only way to resolve it might be to re-install Fedora, I haven't got any data to lose yet, but that does seem a dangerous and long winded way to go about it

Comment: I could saying why someone would want to use emacs ? but I will not, have you try to first type `yum refresh` or `yum check-update` or the command to refresh the repositories ? and then yum install emacs ?

Comment: Or perhaps `yum search emacs` to see if the package is actually called `emacs` ?

Comment: It's in the F20 repositories but you have to install it; the base package is just `emacs` (so: `yum install emacs`), but there are various add-ons, etc, so you may want to look at the output from `yum search emacs` first.

Comment: Can you ping www.google.com and 8.8.8.8  ?

Comment: Thanks @Kiwy, yes I have tried them, all of them and a lot more, no avail, *and* if you don't know why I use emacs, then you haven't lived, yet. And what why those pings and what would they tell me?

Comment: @HarryWeston to check if you're effectively connected on internet, because it seems to be a DNS issue, or maybe you modify your host file to disable abobe.com for a reason and it can't connect to it...

Comment: @Kiwy. thanks, but since I am using this Stack Exchange, email, downloads etc, then surely I *am* connected to the Internet, unless there are various degrees of connection. I have not consciously disabled adobe.com, don't even know how to go about it.

Comment: The recurring problem here is `"Could not resolve host: linuxdownload.adobe.com"`. Something is off with your name resolution. Are you by any chance using a surf proxy for other things?

Comment: And what happens if you try to install some other package? I'd guess that you will get the same problems regardless of what you try to install.

Comment: What does your /etc/resolv.conf look like? If the first nameserver in the list doesn't respond properly, yum may get confused and not try the others.

Comment: Thanks @Jenny. I don't know what a "surf proxy is". and here is the content:`[root@localhost owner]# head /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
domain home
search home
nameserver 192.168.1.254
[root@localhost owner]# ` Sorry I don't know how to get new lines in comments -- pressing enter is the same as "Save edits"

Comment: Also confirm that you can resolve those hostnames that yum is attempting to contact via those `curl` commands. Your issue likely lies w/ your system's inability to get an actual IP for those YUM repositories!

Comment: Also stopping the original `yum` task is blocking any new yum proceses from running. You need to `kill %1` after doing that ^Z!

Comment: @HarryWeston Hi Harry! When you want to add information, it's better to do that as an edit to the question instead of in a comment. But to solve your problem - could you add `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to your resolv.conf and try again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the problem in my question I found `yum` failed every time with

```
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
```

I've been trying to get over this for four days,asking questions all over the place, finally I tried this:

```
[root@localhost owner]# ps < /var/run/yum.pid
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 4126 pts/0    00:00:00 su
 4138 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 4181 pts/0    00:00:00 yum
 4262 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
[root@localhost owner]# kill 4181
[root@localhost owner]# ps < /var/run/yum.pid
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 4126 pts/0    00:00:00 su
 4138 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 4181 pts/0    00:00:00 yum
 4276 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
[root@localhost owner]# cat /var/run/yum.pid
4181[root@localhost owner]# kill -9 4181
[1]+  Killed                  yum install dconf-editor
[root@localhost owner]# cat /var/run/yum.pid
4181[root@localhost owner]# ps < /var/run/yum.pid
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 4126 pts/0    00:00:00 su
 4138 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 4373 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
[root@localhost owner]# yum install xemacs
. . . and off it went
```

and now I have a working XEmacs editor

---

After a lot of frustration I decide to try a well-established version of Fedora instead of the newly released 20 installed by my computer supplier. I have now installed version 17, and, so far, all the problems seem to have been solve. I can now use `yum` with no trouble. I also was apparently missing a lot of the software, like `gnuplot` and `ghostscript`. I suspect that the installer of Fedora 20 had not included the software developer's repositories.

So, now my question is answered, and I have, fingers crossed, upgraded from Fedora 12 to a decent working Fedora again.

Comment: About that, in your question when you stopped yum, it looks like you did it with Ctrl+Z so you really just suspended it, that's why it was still running. To really terminate it's Ctrl+C.

Comment: I don't think you want to use `xemacs` unless you have compelling legacy reasons to stay on a code base which stopped receiving updates years ago.

Answer (score 0):

It is just that emacs isn't in the base set of packages. In the end, POSIX mandates vi(1), not emacs, as the default system editor.

Comment: emacs is in the regular repositories of fedora

Comment: All that vonbrand is saying is why `emacs` isn't installed by default, of course `emacs` is in the default repos.